# Corporates - is there any such word?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

The use of "corporates" as a word to mean companies, organizations, etc., has been gaining popularity of late, at least here in India. Although I believe it is standard to speak of "corporate" life, I'm not sure there's a word like "corporates".

> . . . had been a business consultant to the top **corporates** in the UK

What is your opinion?

Comment: Have you checked in any online dictionaries? Not all list the sense, but try http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/corporate_2 .

Comment: If there wasn't before, there is now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OED has as one of the definitions:

> **corporate** *noun*
>   **1.** *Business*
>   **b.** A large company, a corporation.
>
> > 1945   G. Terborgh *Bogey of Econ. Maturity* ix. 143,   56 corporations offered evidence in the t.n.e.c. hearings... [Note] Included are corporates in mining and manufacturing, transportation and public utilities, trade, service, and construction.

(Definition **a** in this entry, which hasn't been quoted above, has a considerably earlier citation (from 1845), but that's for a now-obsolete use of *corporate* meaning the same as a different, particular sense of *corporation*: "An incorporated company of traders having (originally) the monopoly and control of their particular trade in a borough or other place; a trade-guild, a city ‘company’."

The OED's sense **2**, also not quoted here, lists it as a *US Finance* term for corporate bonds.

Comment: So you mean to say no such word exists now in the sense of "corporations"? However, a link (Cambridge Dictionary) provided in one of comments above says that such usage applies: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/corporate_2
I'm confused!

Comment: @dotslash no, what Andrew is saying is that there *is* such a word, and that this is the OED's earliest citation for it; and further, there are other senses, one with an earlier citation, and one with a different meaning.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was that I could think of using **corporates** for *corporate bonds*, for example, though not for *corporations*.

Generally speaking, however, we know that an adjective can become a noun (substantivation). Then *corporate* may have separated itself from something like **corporate entity** retaining the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: +1 I have also heard tied insurance agents speak of *corporates*  to designate loathsome people from the Home Office, 'corporate types' from the corporation's headquarters.

Comment: @StoneyB, I don't find a problem with **corporate** being mentioned as an adjective. It's the sense of a noun, a corporation, that irks me.

Comment: @dotslash Well, you get a vote, which you may cast repeatedly by a) refusing to use the word in that sense yourself and b) deprecating its use by others in that sense. But everybody else gets a vote, too. We'll just have to wait a generation or so to see who wins.